# Is there a way to perform fire-and-forget AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I'm working on a web app. When the program switches channel, it sends a "close" AJAX request to the server with the old channel. As the server responses, the app just sends an "open" request to the server to open a new channel. Most of times, this close-wait-done-open-wait-done round runs fast enough, but in case of a special channel, close takes longer than 5 secs, which is unacceptable.

I've set a short timeout for these channels' "close" requests, and it returns, but the new "open" request hangs until the server responses the old "close" request, so timeout just pushed the problem away.

I've set up a setTimeout() for the long close, so as my program calls the "close", it will be delayed, and the new "open" performs before it, but it's also just tossing the problem, when setTimeout() hits in, there will be a long request "in the background", which eats up the browser's ajax request pool, and with some luck, causes pseudo-ajax-hanging at a random AJAX request.

The app has no interest in the result of the "close" request, so it can be dropped, even if it fails.

What's the best practice to perform such fire-and-forget AJAX requests?

(I'm using Chromium browser on Linux, but the app should run on Firefox, too.)

Comment: fire ajax-request to your server script. WIth the serwer script curl -close. THat way you get a quick return and the server-side will take care of the closing.

Comment: What's the server-side tech?  Do you have any control over this?  Seems easiest option is to change the "close" server-side method to spawn a new thread/process/background-worker and return immediately.

Comment: Yeah, I have limited access to server-side, I can use JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use servlet 3.0 Async feature. You can commit the response immediately for your close request and start new thread to do further server processing.
You can refer below link for more information on the same.
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html

Comment: This seems to be a serverside fix...it's not even certain the OP's app runs on Java. (JS != Java)

Comment: When i replied i saw java, tomcat and jsp was mentioned in original question.

Comment: Probably, it even can't be solved at client side. Who knows how does acutal and future browsers work. I'll try it and then close the question.