# Is it legal to write and close the response in JSP, then do some extra job?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I'm working on a web app, which is communicating with the server with AJAX requests. A special type of "close" request takes 5 secs, which the web app should just fire-and-forget, the result is irrelevant. Due to browser behaviors (only limited number of simultaneous AJAX requests are performed), a 5-sec request may stuck other AJAX requests, which is unacceptable.

The smart folks here in StackOverflow has adviced me to write a small server-side proxy, which the web app should call instead of the original 5-sec one. The proxy should response immediatelly, close response channel, then perform a HTTP request and wait for it, spending the 5 secs server-side, instead of client-side. (The original question is here: See [Is there a way to perform fire-and-forget AJAX request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592373/is-there-a-way-to-perform-fire-and-forget-ajax-request) )

The server is a Tomcat with JSP, and I can write small JPS pages. (I'm not an experienced JSP ninja, but I don't afraid of Java.) My question is: is it legal to write such a JSP, or what's the best practice:

- send the response,
- close reply channel (is out.close() enough?), in order to end the AJAX request at client-side,
- fire and process (actually: just drop response) a HTTP request "in background", which may take as long as 5 secs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not (only) your browser you should worry about. Blocking a tomcat thread for 5s severly limits your max-users as well (how many requests per second do you need to handle ultimately?)

So making it "more" asynchronous in the server might make sense.

Doing it in JSP (with Sriplets?!) alone will noway be a robust implementation - but if you need to do it that way, you should think about starting the "work to do" in a separate Thread.

So instead of

```
<%
  do_something_heavy();
%>
```

You'll do like

```
<%
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      do_something_heavy();
    }
  }).start();
%>
```

There's other options as well (JMS, ExecutorService, Spring @Async...) but this should get you started quick.

Answer (score 1):

First the best is to separate business logic from view: it means write java code on a servlet and delegate only the view aspect to the jsp.

To execute your task asynchronously in the servlet code you can:

- Invoke a submit method of an ExecutorService
- Make a call to a JMS
- Manually create a thread and start it

Then you can forward to the jsp.

TIP: It is possible to assign an id to the long task and return it in the jsp with a link to monitor the status of the task.

Basically you do something like that:

1. Accept the request
2. Start asynchronously a thread to execute the long task
3. Return immediately without waiting for the long task termination

Or using an id:

1. Accept the request
2. Calculate the id of the task
3. Start asynchronously a thread to execute the long task with the desired id
4. Return immediately a link with the id of the long task without waiting for the termination